# How to access the attributes of another class in the a class method

Tags: java, object, oop, generics, methods

Basically, I wanted to print (robot_name "is owned by" person_name) where robot_name is the atrribute of class Robot and person_name is of class Person.
I am printing this in method of class Person named as isOwnedby()

Actually, I want to access rname attribute of r1 object of class Robot in the function of class Person named as isOwnedby(). But, iam getteing following errors,

error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(r1.rname() + "is owned by" + this.name);
^
symbol:   variable r1
location: class Person

The code snippet is as follows,

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Robot class objects
        Robot r1 = new Robot("Jerry", "Red", 30);
        r1.introduceself();
        Robot r2 = new Robot("Tom", "Blue", 40);
        r2.introduceself();
        
        //Person class objects
        Person p1 = new Person("Alice", "Aggresive", false);
        Person p2 = new Person("Becky", "Talkative", true);
        p1.robotOwned = r2;
            p2.robotOwned = r1;
        
        p1.robotOwned.introduceself(); //same as r2.introduceself()
        p2.robotOwned.introduceself(); //same as r1.introduceself()
        p1.isOwnedby();
    }
}

class Robot 
{
    String rname;
    String color;
    int weight;
    
    //constructor
    Robot (String n, String c, int w)
    {
        this.rname = n;
        this.color = c;
        this.weight = w;
    }
    
    void introduceself()
    {
        System.out.println("My name is " + this.rname);
    }
    
    public String rname()
    {
        return rname;
    }
}

class Person
{
    String name;
    String personality;
    boolean isSitting;
    Robot robotOwned;
    
    //constructor
    Person (String n, String p, boolean i)
    {
        this.name = n;
        this.personality = p;
        this.isSitting = i;
    }
    
    
    //methods
    
    void isOwnedby()
    {
        System.out.println(r1.rname() + "is owned by" + this.name);
    }
      
    public String pname()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So `r1` is not accessible from within the `Person` class, because it is not defined there.  You're going to need to use the local `robotOwned` object instead:

```
private void isOwnedby() {
    System.out.println(robotOwned.rname() + "is owned by" + this.name);
}
```

Additional recommendations:

- Avoid single-character variable names.  Descriptive variable names are better for everyone.
- It's usually a good idea to only have one Java class per file.
- delux247 has a good idea about checking for null before trying to return the robot's name.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
System.out.println(r1.rname() + "is owned by" + this.name);
```

to

```
if(robotOwned != null){
  System.out.println(robotOwned.rname() + "is owned by" + this.name);
} else{
  System.out.println(this.name + " does not own a robot");
}
```